# Understanding winfo_exists()

Tags: python, tkinter

I’m trying to test the existence of a toplevel using the winfo_exists() method made available by Tkinter.

However, I cannot test the existence of a Toplevel by passing the name of this to winfo_exists() method.

I enclose a script to better clarify what I would like to do.
When you open the app, four buttons are shown. Pressing on the first appears a mask where we can, by pressing the relevant buttons, see the execution of both the winfo_exists() method and the winfo_children() method.

Selecting a Toplevel to test using the radiobox on the right happens that if the relative Toplevel is open the function work fine, otherwise generates the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "/home/bc/Desktop/simple_app.py", line 113, in on_test_exist
if self.nametowidget(DICT_TOPLEVELS[self.option.get()]).winfo_exists():
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1353, in nametowidget
w = w.children[n]
KeyError: 'toptwo'
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Basically in an application with many Toplevels, how do you see if a certain Toplevel is open?

Thank you for your attention.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

DICT_TOPLEVELS = {0:".topone",
                  1:".toptwo",
                  2:".topthree"}

        
class Main(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, ):
        super().__init__(name="main")

        self.parent = parent
        self.init_ui()
      
    def init_ui(self):

        f0 = tk.Frame(self)

        bts = [("Top One", 4, self.on_open_one, "<Alt-o>"),
               ("Top Two", 4, self.on_open_two, "<Alt-t>"),
               ("Top Three", 5, self.on_open_three, "<Alt-w>"),
               ("Close", 0, self.parent.on_exit, "<Alt-c>")]

        for btn in bts:
            ttk.Button(f0,
                       text=btn[0],
                       underline=btn[1],
                       command = btn[2]).pack(fill=tk.X, padx=5, pady=5)
            self.parent.bind(btn[3], btn[2])
            
        
        f0.pack()

        
    def on_open_one(self, evt=None):

       obj = TopOne(self)
       obj.on_open()

    def on_open_two(self, evt=None):

       obj = TopTwo(self)
       obj.on_open()

    def on_open_three(self, evt=None):

        obj = TopThree(self)
        obj.on_open()
        
class TopOne(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent,):
        super().__init__(name="topone")

        self.parent = parent
        self.minsize(200, 100)
        self.voices = ('topone','toptwo','topthree')
        self.option = tk.IntVar()
        self.init_ui()
        
    def init_ui(self):

        f0 = tk.Frame(self, bg='SlateGray4', padx=5,pady=5)
        f1 = tk.Frame(f0,)

        bts = [("Call winfo_exists", 7, self.on_winfo_exists, "<Alt-c>"),
               ("Get winfo_children", 0, self.on_get_winfo_children, "<Alt-g>"),
               ("Test exist", 0, self.on_test_exist, "<Alt-t>"),
               ("Close", 0, self.master.on_exit, "<Alt-c>")]

        for btn in bts:
            ttk.Button(f1,
                       text=btn[0],
                       underline=btn[1],
                       command = btn[2]).pack(fill=tk.X, padx=5, pady=5)
            self.parent.bind(btn[3], btn[2])

        f2 = tk.Frame(f0,)
        ttk.Label(f2, text="Toplevels:").pack()
        for index, text in enumerate(self.voices):
            ttk.Radiobutton(f2,
                            text=text,
                            variable=self.option,
                            value=index,).pack()

            
        f0.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        f2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y, padx=5, pady=5, expand=0)
        f1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y, padx=5, pady=5, expand=0)

    def on_open(self):
        msg = "{0}".format(self.winfo_name().title())
        self.title(msg)

    def on_winfo_exists(self, evt=None):

        for obj in  self.nametowidget(".").winfo_children():
            if self.nametowidget(obj).winfo_exists():
                print("{0} is exist!".format(self.nametowidget(obj).winfo_name()))
           
    def on_get_winfo_children(self, evt=None):

        for obj in  self.nametowidget(".").winfo_children():
            print(self.master.nametowidget(obj))

    def on_test_exist(self):

        print("You have selected to test if {0} Toplevel exist.".format(DICT_TOPLEVELS[self.option.get()]),)
        
        if self.nametowidget(DICT_TOPLEVELS[self.option.get()]).winfo_exists():
            print("Well Toplevel named {0} exists!".format(self.nametowidget(DICT_TOPLEVELS[self.option.get()]).winfo_name()))
        else:
            print("I’m sorry but Toplevel named {0} doesn’t exist!".format(DICT_TOPLEVELS[self.option.get()]))

class TopTwo(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent,):
        super().__init__(name="toptwo")

        self.parent = parent
        self.minsize(200, 100)
        self.init_ui()
        
    def init_ui(self):

        f = tk.Frame(self, bg='DarkSeaGreen4', padx=5,pady=5)
        f.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1, padx=5, pady=5)

    def on_open(self):
        msg = "{0}".format(self.winfo_name().title())
        self.title(msg)

class TopThree(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent,):
        super().__init__(name="topthree")

        self.parent = parent
        self.minsize(200, 100)
        self.init_ui()
        
    def init_ui(self):

        f = tk.Frame(self, bg='DarkSeaGreen3', padx=5,pady=5)
        f.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1, padx=5, pady=5)

    def on_open(self):
        msg = "{0}".format(self.winfo_name().title())
        self.title(msg)          
        

class App(tk.Tk):
    """Main Application start here"""
    def __init__(self,):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_exit)
        #self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.geometry('400x200')
        self.title("Simple App")
        Main(self).pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    def on_exit(self):
        msg = "Do you want to quit?"
        if messagebox.askokcancel(self.title(), msg, parent=self):
            self.destroy()

def main():
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't the answer obvious? You can check if the error happens using `try/except`, if the error happens, then the window does not exist. I don't quite get your main question

Comment: @Delrius Euphoria
Not so obvious to me, because as reported here [Google](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/winfo+exists) I expected that winfo_exists()  returned 0 not an error.

Comment: The error is not from `winfo_exists`, it is from `nametowidget`. If you check the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/575f8880bf8498ee05a8e197fc2ed85db6880361/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L1563), you will see that `nametowidget` uses `w = w.children[n]` to find it from a dictionary of all its child.

Comment: @Delrius Euphoria..mumble mumble..here seems to work [How to test...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44511793/11211759) and looking at the source code you’re right, but then I wonder what I need this method for... I am a bit confused.

Comment: Of course `winfo_exists` work, but the way you are using it is giving the error. `winfo_exists` is required to be called on a widget, but `nametowidget` cannot return a widget because the widget does not exist. If you wrote the code in question on your own, this should be pretty straightforward to understand, unless I'm missing what you are asking.

Comment: @Delrius Euphoria "The widget does not start to begin with" but I call it by name as I do in a function looping self.nametowidget(".").winfo_children()..I’m sorry I can’t get there.Of course the code is mine ;)

Comment: That function loops through "all the available children" of the root window. But your version of `nametowidget` looks for a specific widget in a cluster of widget and when it is not found, an error is raised.

Comment: So if the widget does not exist what does winfo_exists() serve, when could it return 0? I say that because I've read the tcl/tk documentation that report "Returns 1 if there exists a window named window, 0 if no such window exists.",  thank you for your patience.

Comment: _"So if the widget does not exist what does winfo_exists() serve, when could it return 0?"_ - when the python object that represents the window exists, but the actual widget has been destroyed. For example, `t = tk.Toplevel(); t.destroy(); t.winfo_exists()` returns `0`.